# Sending formData object from react typescript to .NET API, but received null in the backend

Tags: c#, reactjs, .net, postman, react-typescript

trying to send an array of FormData objects from React typescript to .NET API, but received null in the backend, I tried to add content type like multipart/formdata but still not working,  I tried it from postman it works like this:

```
models[0].name:sub test 7
models[0].order:7
models[0].processID:176

models[1].name:sub test 5
models[1].order:5
models[1].processID:176
```

my frontend testing code:

```
 let models = [
    { name: "test1", order: 1, processID: 169 },
    { name: "test2", order: 2, processID: 169 },
];
let subProcessInputModels = new FormData();
subProcessInputModels.append("models", JSON.stringify(models));
SubProcessService.createSubProcess(subProcessInputModels).then((response) =>
  console.log("response", response)
)
```

Comment: Hi, Why do you want it to be sent from React as form data? What you are doing here is formating it as json, so send it as json ;)

Comment: @Hassan-Ismail: Could you please show the controller action method signature?

Comment: @KrzysiekSzymczak I'm sending it as FormData because I have to send image in the form

Comment: @HassanIsmail can you show us your backend code? Or maybe prepare some github repo with this code so I can take a closer look ;) ?